# What do you call this type of top down grid, sort of trapezoidal?

Tags: illustration, perspective

[image]

I have checked and this may be called Top-Down (Oblique) from the wikipedia page of Axonometric projection BUT the image I am looking for kinda have that trapezoidal nature. As you can see the grids aren't necessarily straight. Any clues?

Comment: what is this image from? Looks like a fun game.

Comment: "All wrong" comes to mind :) I can't decide if the characters are standing up on a deformed rectangle titled towards the viewer, or flat cut-outs leaning backwards, away from the viewpoint.

Comment: It is called Eiyuu Senki by Tenco. @Vincent.

Comment: The perspective might throw you off, but this kinds of orientation is normal in these games @usr2564301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: 3 kinds of perspective.]

The image seems to contain three different perspectives:

1. The tiles (magenta) are drawn using *two-point perspective*. The x-axis is parallel to the picture plane while the lines parallel to the y-axis converge to vanishing point *A* (backwards) and the lines parallel to the z-axis converge to vanishing point *B* (downwards).
2. The characters (cyan) doesn't really have perspective. They are just flat sprites seen from the side. The rear character seems to bee a little bit smaller than the others, so there might be some scaling going on. In lack of a better term I would call it *two and a half dimensional* or *2.5D*.
3. The background (orange) is drawn using a classic *two-point perspective* with the two vanishing points, C and D, placed on the horizon.

This style of graphics might have a proper name in the (japanese?) gaming industry, but I'm not aware of it.

I don't think there is a special mathematical logic behind it. It's really just a collage of images, cleverly placed and sized in an attempt to give a three-dimensional illusion.

Wikipedia on [perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)).

Wikipedia on [2.5D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D).

Comment: This is the closest explanation i can have. The details on how the image is formed is the biggest clue i have right now. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your vanishing point B. It's "just a skewed rectagle" so shouldn't it be 1-Point-Perspective?

Comment: @BlueWizard, it's not just a skewed rectangle - it's a 3d box skewed in two dimensions. Look at the thickness of the board (in the original image). The lines parallel to the z-axis are in fact not vertical, but converge to a point. Try zooming in on one of the bottom corners of the image.

Answer (score 4):

Its not in the family of axonometric projections. So it is either in the family of perspective, some random projection or it is not a projection at all.

I would just call it a perspective grid. This is also by the way why a image is worth more than a thousand words as there really is no name for half of what you see. Only a rather leg thy and misinterpretation prone description.

Comment: Thanks! That limits the things i have to look up. "Perspective grid", ill put that in mind!